# With one connection (config) displays data, with other not

Tags: php, config

I am trying to develop a script that I found in internet (search/autosuggestion). The script is very small, but the problem I think is in connection, configuration file. I found, that the old connection style is working properly with script, but if I am using "define" connection, than all script stops working, and does not display any data.

**Old connection**

```
$host="aha";
$user="aha";
$pass="aha";
$base="aha";
$connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($base, $connect);
?>
```

**Define connection do not work with script**

```
define("DB_HOST", "aha");
define("DB_NAME", "aha");
define("DB_USER", "aha");
define("DB_PASS", "aha");
```

I believe, that the script is wrote in very old code, so I guess, that this very small script should be rewritten in new way, but the question is, how should I do it properly?

**The script**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if($_POST)

{

$q=$_POST['searchword'];

$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from users where user_firstname like '%$q%' or user_lastname like '%$q%' order by user_id LIMIT 5");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$fname=$row['user_firstname'];
$lname=$row['user_lastname'];
$email=$row['user_email'];

$re_fname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';
$re_lname='<b>'.$q.'</b>';

$final_fname = str_ireplace($q, $re_fname, $fname);

$final_lname = str_ireplace($q, $re_lname, $lname);


?>

<div class="display_box" align="left">

<a href="http://www.google.com/">

<img src="user_img/y.jpg" style="width:25px; float:left; margin-right:6px" /><?php echo $final_fname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $final_lname; ?><br/>
<span style="font-size:9px; color:#999999"><?php echo $email; ?></span>

</a>

</div>

<?php }} else {} ?>
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work fine...as long as your config.php can reference the variables correctly (i.e. they are either declared in that file itself or declared elsewhere and included in the config.php file).

config.php:

```
<?
define("DB_HOST", "aha");
define("DB_NAME", "aha");
define("DB_USER", "aha");
define("DB_PASS", "aha");

$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But i guess, i should wrote script in pdo. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your new connection config your not actually establishing a database connection, your simply defining constants.

There are many libraries that abstract the database layer to help make your code more readable and automate things like escaping etc. You should probably look at something like pdo http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: As i thought, pdo is best way for this script. However it is problem for me :). Anyway, thanks for help.